# Java class extend Applet and Keylistener?

Tags: java, html, applet

I have a three classes to make a Snake game, Snake, GameBoard and The_Main. The_Main uses    'KeyAdapter' to read in from the keyboard to the declaration is 
`public class The_main extends KeyAdapter{`

But I also want to put this game on a html page, so I'm planning on putting it in an applet, using the following code:

```
 <html>
 <title>Applet Test</title>
 <body>
 <applet
    archive = "TheSnake.jar"
    code = "theSnake/The_Main.class"
     width="800" 
    height="800">
 </applet>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I load the webpage, it gives me a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. I don't know how to get the stack trace, if you guys needed that..

Comment: One class can't extend two classes, if that is the question. Please give us more info.

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot extend multiple classes in Java](http://www.coderanch.com/t/380144/java/java/Why-cannot-java-class-extend). You [can implement multiple interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html), but this is not what you're looking for.

You should have a class that extends `Applet`, then one that extends `KeyAdapter`. You can then reference the `KeyAdapter` class *from* the `Applet` class.

An `Applet` like this (in `MyApplet.class`, for your HTML):

```
public MyApplet extends Applet implements Runnable {
    // ...
    public someMethod() {
        MyKeyAdapter adapter = new MyKeyAdapter();
        // Do some stuff with `adapter`
    }
}
```

Then, your `KeyAdapter` (not used in the HTML; *only* called from Java):

```
public MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
    // ...
}
```